# Not redirecting after requests.post django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I'm currently using django rest framework api and I have a form to enter some api information in.

I'd like to redirect after I submit my form while still POSTing the data to the API url using the requests library.

However the `HttpResponseRedirect` isn't triggering a redirect for some reason

Here is my `views.py`

```
from rest_frame.requests import reverse
import requests

def entry_new(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            url = reverse("entry-list",request=request)
            r = requests.post(url, data=request.POST, cookies=request.COOKIES)
            ## THIS IS WHAT ISN'T FIRING - it goes back to entry_new's URL
            HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index2'))
    else:
        form = EntryForm

    return render(request, 'entry_new.html', {'form': form})

class entry_ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Entry.objects.all()
    serializer_class= EntrySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.partial = True
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user, modified_by=self.request.user, modified_date=datetime.now())
```

my `serializers.py`

```
class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='created_by.username')
    modified_by = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='modified_by.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = '__all__'
```

my `urls.py`

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'entry', views.entry_ViewSet, base_name="entry")

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index2/$',views.index_two, name='index2'), 
    url(r'^cat_new/$', views.category_new, name='cat_new'),
    url(r'^entry_new/$', views.entry_new, name='entry_new'),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    ]
```

Comment: You missed the `return` before the redirect.

Comment: You need to return the response after you create it.

Comment: Also if you are using an internal URL it might be better to call the handler directly instead of using requests.

Comment: wow - talk about completely brainfarting. Thanks all!

Comment: Why would you do that ? Doesn't really make sense for an API does it ?

Comment: I am now separating the redirect from the API POST. The entry_new is a page with a form to create new entries and POST them. I don't know how to call the POST serializer from within the entry_new view so I'm using requests to call the URL to POST it. Is there a better way?